# How to validate form field with Parsley JS if field input has been populated automatically?

Tags: parsley.js

I have a signup form where the user is supposed to enter amongst other personal details also his phone number's country prefix (e.g. '+49' for Germany). Now I have a script running which automatically detects the country prefix according to the user's IP geo location.
If the IP location is successfully determining the user's current location, it puts the country code automatically in the signup form's prefix field.

This means that the user doesn't have to enter the prefix manually.

My question is: once the signup form is loading, and all fields are empty except for the country prefix, how can I validate the country prefix field successfully prior to hitting the submit button?

I tried all kinds of triggers from the [jQuery Events page](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/) as suggested by the [ParsleyJS documentation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/) but I don't get it done..

Any help on this would be gladly appreciated!

**Edit** to further clarify: If you're visiting the signup page, the IP location script detects your location, translates that into your country's phone prefix, and puts that number into the "Prefix" form field. So you don't have to put there anymore by yourself. This works only if the the IP locations script successfully identifies your location of course, however this works in most of the cases. So what I would like to achieve is that this form gets it's green validated background, although you didn't put in the prefix yourself. In other words, the prefix is already in the field in most of the cases. 
I'm using the data-parsley-triggers, no jQuery or JS to validate the whole form.

[image]

You can see in the picture that I entered a first name, Foo, which validated upon `data-parsley-trigger="change"`. The blue arrows show the fields which have been filled automatically by the IP location - and they are not validated as I'm missing the right trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve (why validate the field when it's clear it will be valid), but why not simple `$('input[name="phone_prefix"]').parsley().validate()`?

Comment: Please see my "Edit" in the my original question as the comment space wasn't enough...

Comment: I added your snippet, and now it works! Thanks a lot!